# Windows Phone 7 Application Code Obfuscation

Tags: windows-phone-7

About to complete a wp7 application, which uses bing map services for locations etc. I need to know if obfuscation will hamper its performance.

There are some tools available like Dotfuscator etc, but concerned about the performance of the app. Please give your suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not have much experience with obfuscation, however what I do know is there are two methods.

1. Simply renaming of variables and functions to make it difficult to read the logic when decompiled using Reflector; and
2. The other where program flow is be rearranged.

With name obfuscation the IL code and runtime performance is the same. There is apparently a difference in performance with the second method, however the only benchmarks/articles I can find are for Java.

You are deploying to a secure device and file system <s>so there is no need to obfuscate a WP7 application</s>. As Chris pointed out, you can actually get the application package file by intercepting the HTTP request from the marketplace and extracting the GUID as detailed in a [blog post by Marius Gheorghe](http://www.voidsoft.ro/blog/post/How-to-downloads-app-from-the-WP7-marketplace.aspx). As Marius explains this is because the XML stream is not encrypted and that the assembly package can be retrieved using a simple request. I would expect Microsoft to patch/fix this soon (and I will mention it to our Microsoft account manager).

As for WP7 obfuscation there is a [detailed blog post here](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2010/11/16/Code-Obfuscation-and-Windows-Phone-7-Application-Protection.aspx) that should help.

...

If you want to secure your application, I would spent the time encrypting your persisted data (i.e. save files) so that your users data is secure. That is what did for the WP7 [Full House Poker](http://wmpoweruser.com/full-house-poker-this-weeks-xbox-live-title-released/) game.

Comment: You *do* need to obfuscate. Fire up Fiddler and browse the marketplace with Zune, pull the download URL out of the XML and use it download your xap. Unzip, load dlls in favourite tool and all the code is there. Don't even need to purchase the app.

Comment: Really? I have not published an application/game for 12 months so it has changed since then. Thanks for the information Chris.

Comment: Updated my answer with new information. Thanks once again for pointing this out Chris.

Answer (score 4):

There is only one way to be sure: you should test.

Obfuscation will probably not impact performance much but, again, you should test.

**EDIT**

Before you obfuscate, do realize that obfuscation is not the same as encryption. Never store any secrets in your client side code!

Answer (score -2):

Performance is hampered but ignorable if you measure in milliseconds, the bottom line is that you may do not obfuscate if you are creating a free application or open source.

Comment: Could you explain why you consider this the answer to your question? Will performance be hampered and not ignorable when you measure in hours? Is there no risk of losing intellectual property when the app is free?

Comment: I meant to say that obfuscation hits performance negligible and cannot be measured by human eye. So, we should go for it unless we are creating a open source / free app which we want to share with others